# understanding why a function vanishes when it is holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis

> $\displaystyle\frac{\overline{a}}{1-|a|^2}\int_{\mathbb{T}_1(0)}\frac{dz}{\overline{a}z-1}$, where $a\in \mathbb{C}, |a|\neq 1$ if $|a|<1$ then the integrand is holomorphic inside the interior of unit disc and the integral vanishes.

$\mathbb{T}_1(0)$ is the unit circle, now what I dont see are (1) why $\frac{1}{\overline{a}z-1}$ is holomorphic when $|a|<1$ and furthermore, (2) why does it vanish inside the interior even when its holomorphic?

Here is what I've thought about, to see its holomorphic, I tried to use the definition of complex differentiation to show all primes exists inside the interior take $z_0\in D_1(0)$ and I arrived at $\displaystyle\lim_{z \to z_{0}}\,\,\,\frac{-\overline{a}\left(z^{2} - z_{0}^{2}\,\right)}{\overline{a}^2z_{0}\,z-\overline{a}\left(z + z_{0}\right)+1}$, frankly I don't see how modulus of $a$ determines this limit exists.

If you can help me understand this, it would be really helpful to me!
Thanks

Comment: Does the denominator of your function vanish anywhere in the unit disc?

Comment: The question is not whether the *integrand* vanishes but the *integral*

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I think some magic happens when $z=a$ inside the interior?

Comment: And if it is really $\overline(az}$ then the integrand is not holomorphic anywhere. If the bar is just over the $a,$ however...

Comment: @remu, i don't think you will be able to solve this is you cannot decide whether the function $\bar a z-1$ vanishes or not in the unit disc. This is at least four orders of magnitude a more basic question than the one you asked.

Comment: As Igor Rivin has said, your quote is not correctly stated. Whether this is so in your source or you misquoted that source here, I cannot say. But the correct statement is that when $|a| < 1$, the *integrand* is holomorphic and **the integral** vanishes. The integral vanishes by Cauchy's theorem. The integrand is holomorphic because the function $\frac 1{\bar az - 1}$ is holomorphic everywhere except when $\bar az - 1 = 0$, and when $|a| < 1$, that does not occur inside or on the unit circle.